# Saving change to an Entity which is mapped to a View

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Can I use Entity Framework to save changes to a view?

I have an entity which is mapped to a View.

```
[Table("MyView")]
public class MyEntity
{
    public long MyEntityId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The View itself is like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
SELECT 
    t.MyEntityId,
    t.Name,
FROM 
    MyTable t
```

Would I be able to use Entity Framework change tracking to save changes to this View? So is something like this possible:

```
var record = Context.MyEntity.Where(e => e.MyEntityId == 150).FirstOrDefault();
record.Name = "New Name";
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Entity Framework does not care if the Entity is mapped to a View or Table... it would just create the same update script. For the example above EF generates the following script:

```
UPDATE [MyView] SET [Name]=@gp1 WHERE [MyEntityId] = 150
-- @gp1: 'New Name' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 8)
```

So EF does not introduce any additional limitation for updating a View... but we still have the RDBMS specific limitations for updating a View... as an example, in SQL Server a view can be updated [subject to the following limitations](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130855&seqNum=4):

> - If the view contains joins between multiple tables, you can only    insert and update one table in the view, and you can't delete rows.
> - You can't directly modify data in views based on union queries. You    can't modify data in views that use GROUP BY or DISTINCT statements.
> - All columns being modified are subject to the same restrictions as if    the statements were being executed directly against the base
>     table.
> - Text and image columns can't be modified through views.
> - There is no checking of view criteria. For example, if the view    selects all customers who live in Paris, and data is modified to
>     either add or edit a row that does not have City = 'Paris', the data
>     will be modified in the base table but not shown in the view, unless
>     WITH CHECK OPTION is used when defining the view.